# Creating a side-scrolling website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a website that scrolls horizontally with a fixed character in the centre, similar to http://www.rleonardi.com/interactive-resume/.

When trying to change the css to resize the images it doesnt affect the website and I dont know if I need to use the position:fixed to fix the character in the centre.

[background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CoX1P.jpg)

[floor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0Aqb.png)

[character](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cw13.png)

```
    <html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Your title</title>
    <link   rel="stylesheet"    href="css/styles.css">
</head>

    <body>

       <background><img src="Photos/Backgroundclear%20.png" alt= "Background"/> </background> 


       <character><img src="Photos/Character.png" alt= "Background image"/> </character> 


       <div><floor><img src="Photos/floor.png" alt= "Background image"/> </floor> </div>


    </body>
```

and css:

```
body{
    background-color: $primarycolour;
    max-width: 8000px;
    max-height: auto;

}

background{
    max-height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;

}

character{
    max-height: 20px;
    margin: auto; 

}
```

Comment: You better wrap your code into Fiddle. Your css is not doing any resize at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a complex project like this you're really going to have to wrap your head around the positioning of elements and how fixed/relative and absolute positioning work. [This](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp) should set you on the right track. In this case I used chrome inspector to have a look at the example that you are trying to replicate and I can see that the character has `position: absolute`. Here's some css with the character resized. Hope it helps!

```
body{
    background-color: $primarycolour;
    max-width: 8000px;
    max-height: auto;

}

background{
    max-height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;

}

character{
    max-height: 20px;
    margin: auto; 

}
background img {
    width: 100%;
}
floor img {
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
}
character img {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    bottom: 140px;
    left: calc(50% - 100px);
}
```